# What is the difference between .log and .txt?

Tags: php, file, logging

Is there any functional difference between

```
file_put_contents( '/Users/jake/Development/testing.log', ob_get_clean(), FILE_APPEND );
```

and

```
file_put_contents( '/Users/jake/Development/testing.txt', ob_get_clean(), FILE_APPEND );
```

?

I can open both files in sublime text 2, and I'm not sure what the difference between the extensions is.

Comment: Extensions do not have any inherent meaning, they are just a way of tagging files -- hinting to what their content might be and which application might be best to open them.

Comment: @Jon Yea, windows takes extensions a little further though. In the *nix realm extensions are really just a heads up identifier, while windows treats extensions more strictly (which I think is silly but whatever).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No there is no difference. You can use either. For convention and to show the purpose log files use .log extension.

and yes you can usually open them with any text editor.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response