# what is the difference between .log and .txt's access rights?

Tags: file, logging

[What is the difference between log and txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934530/what-is-the-difference-between-log-and-txt)

Refering to the above post I have a question.

Can we access log file simultaneosly from two different processes?
i.e. can we write to .log file from two different processes at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. A .log file is the same as a .txt file, only with a different extension. As the accepted answer in your linked question says:

> there is no difference.

Comment: Thanks @computerfreaker. The real purpose of this question was to find answer for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713025/log4net-write-file-located-at-shared-drive

Comment: I can't answer that question, unfortunately, since I'm not familiar with the log4net software. But I do think your guess (logfile locked by one user = missed entries from other users) is a reasonable one.

Comment: @MARKANDBhatt If my answer answered this question for you, please don't forget to accept it by clicking the green checkmark next to it. Thanks!